# AJAX callback to retrieve layers name from GeoServer fails with an assertion error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, openlayers-3, geoserver

I'm writing something to get all the layers names from my GeoServer. This is my code:

```
function getData() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities",
        type: 'GET'
    });
}

function onComplete(data) {

    var parser = new ol.format.WMSCapabilities();
    var result = parser.read(data.responseText);

    var layersArray = result.Capability.Layer.Layer;
    layersNameArray = [];

    for(i=0;i<layersArray.length;i++){
        layersNameArray.push(layersArray[i].Name)
    }

    return layersNameArray
}

getData().done(onComplete)
```

I'm far from an expert with asynchronous calls, but I think this one is supposed to work. If I stock the `getData()` result in a variable and run the  `onComplete()` function line by line, the code works. But when I run the code with `getData().done(onComplete)`, it always fails at the `var result = parser.read(data.responseText);`line with `Assertion error: Failure`.

Any idea why this isn't working ?

**Edit:**

This code works, but nothing is returned. I want the function to output the `layersNameArray`variable. How should I proceed ?

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(response) {
            var parser = new ol.format.WMSCapabilities();
            var result = parser.read(response);

            var layersArray = result.Capability.Layer.Layer;
            layersNameArray = [];

            for(i=0;i<layersArray.length;i++){
                layersNameArray.push(layersArray[i].Name)
            }

            return layersNameArray
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you are not waiting for the ajax call to complete and the server to return back the values. you must wait!! call the oncomplete function from within your success method of the ajax

Comment: `run the  onComplete() function line by line, the code works` this works because by the time you reach the line your server would have sent back the result.

Comment: Can you suggest a working example with my code ? At first I was trying to call the function within the success method but It wasn't working

Comment: That is how you need to call it, what is not working when you try calling from success method?

Comment: I edited the main post, it works with the success method but how can I access the resulting variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the Jquery callback feature,

make a call to your function this way,

```
getData(function(responsefromAjax){
   alert('the response from ajax is :' +responsefromAjax);
  // what ever logic that needs to run using this ajax data
 });
```

And the make change to your method this way.

```
function getData(callback) { // passing the function as parameter
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(response) {
            var parser = new ol.format.WMSCapabilities();
            var result = parser.read(response);

            var layersArray = result.Capability.Layer.Layer;
            layersNameArray = [];

            for(i=0;i<layersArray.length;i++){
                layersNameArray.push(layersArray[i].Name)
            }

            callback(layersNameArray); //this will execute your function defined during the function call. As you have passed the function as parameter.
        }
    });
}
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: It works but I can't use the output of the getData() function as it stills shows undefined if I try to get the result in a variable. The alert works fine because it waits for the call to be finished before showing, but I need to access the result directly to put in a comboBox field after the user click on a button.

Comment: ajax is asynchronous call , the rest of the code continue to execute after making a ajax call. So if your intention is to use the ajax returned data in some logic of yours you must do it only after success call. So either change your code to execute your logic in ajax success or you can write your logic inside the `getData` function at the place where the alert is placed.

Comment: You cannot order a pizza online and immediately start eating it. you got to wait for it to get delivered , only then you can eat. Its the same thing here in AJAX